# Advice on how/where to deploy a React/Golang app?

Tags: reactjs, go, deployment

I finished my first fullstack (React/Go) app and everything works locally but I'm having trouble with the next steps especially since I'm new to this. I read Heroku was a good choice and I was able to successfully deploy my Go code there and test it via Postman, however I'm having trouble getting my React code introduced so when I visit the Heroku app it displays the React UI. Is this an option on Heroku? Both my frontend and backend code are in the same Github repo if that makes any difference. Any advice how to both deployed together?

I'm pretty sure I have to use the build version of my React code but not sure how to go from there. Go can also be compiled into an executable. Could I theoretically do everything using just this executable and the React build project? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend trying https://firebase.google.com - you can deploy apps for free, you'll get a free '.web.app' host, and you have some DB solutions also available for free, if you ever need them. The easiest way would - to compile everything into a `build` folder or something and simply upload it there. You can later buy a domain name and link it, but for the start is should be sufficient as it is.